Verbposition nach dem Komma
Auffällig stehen die jeweiligen Anteile von persönlicher Begabung an der Spitze, am höchsten ist der Anteil von Sprach- und Naturwissenschaften 94%, danach folgen Ingenieurwissenschaften.
Auffällig stehen die jeweiligen Anteile von persönlicher Begabung an der Spitze, am höchsten ist der Anteil von Sprach- und Naturwissenschaften 94%, gefolgt von Ingenieurwissenschaften.
Auffällig ist, dass die jeweiligen Anteile von persönlicher Begabung an der Spitze stehen, am höchsten ist der Anteil von Sprach- und Naturwissenschaften 94%, danach folgen Ingenieurwissenschaften.
Auffällig ist, dass die jeweiligen Anteile von persönlicher Begabung an der Spitze stehen, am höchsten ist der Anteil von Sprach- und Naturwissenschaften 94%, gefolgt von Ingenieurwissenschaften.
Ich würde gern wissen,warum das Verb nach dem Komma manchmal in Position 1, manchmal Position 2 liegt und die Grammatik immer korrekt ist? unabhängig vom Vorhandensein von "dass" im Satz.

Man kann sagen "Der Anteil ist hoch; er beträgt 94%", aber nicht "am höchsten beträgt der Anteil".

Der zweite Satzteil, "...am höchsten beträgt..." ist ein Hauptsatz, der an den ersten Teil mit einem Komma angedockt ist (er könnte auch vorkommen alleine stehen), "beträgt" ist ein Prädikat (das daher im Hauptsatz an Position 2 stehen muss).
Der dritte Satzteil "...gefolgt von..." ist zwar in gewisser Weise eine Verbform, allerdings ein alleine stehendes Partizip, also kein Prädikat, sondern wird eher behandelt wie ein Adjektiv - Das muss natürlich nicht an Position 2 stehen. In deinem anderen Beispiel verwendest du "...danach folgen..." - Das ist tatsächlich eine finite Verbform in einem Hauptsatz, und die muss wiederum an die Position 2.
Der Teil mit dem "...dass..." hat an sich überhaupt nichts mit deiner Beobachtung zu tun. Das ist ein (anderer) Nebensatz.
